# How can i make it clearly Guessing game?

Tags: java

how can i do that someone ?
i had problem about that

Enter the mode: A
Enter the minimal possible integer: 1
Enter the maximal possible integer: 10
I have generated a random integer between 1 and 10.
Try to guess: 5
No. It is smaller!
Try to guess: 3
Done.

---

Enter the mode: B
Enter the minimal possible integer: 1
Enter the maximal possible integer: 10
Generate a random integer between 1 and 10...
Which method I should use to guess it?
   1: Binary search
   2: Interpolation search
Enter your choice of the method: 1
Is it 5? (<, >, =)
<

## Is it 3?

Done.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i dont understand second one i did first but second how can i do that ?

Comment: Show us your coding attempt with specific questions and we can help...

Comment: i just new started to learn.. just i did first part but here i dont know what should i do ;
1 Enter the maximal possible integer: 10 Generate a random integer between 1 and 10... Which method I should use to guess it? 1: Binary search 2: Interpolation search Enter your choice of the method: 1 Is it 5? (<, >, =) <
Is it 3?

Done.

Comment: So Mode A is where the PROGRAM selects a number in the specified range and YOU need to guess it. Mode B is where YOU select a number in the specified range and the PROGRAM needs to guess it with the SEARCH PATTERN selected. This is an assignment where you can easily GOOGLE all the parts.

Comment: i just dont understand how can i find 1: binary search 2: interpolation search :( i need to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning different search algorithms is very interesting.
Since you say that you need to learn, I present you the theoretical explanation of both algorithms.

## ***Binary search***

This is a computer science search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array. Binary search compares the target value to the middle element of the array. If they are not equal, the half in which the target cannot lie is eliminated and the search continues on the remaining half, again taking the middle element to compare to the target value, and repeating this until the target value is found. If the search ends with the remaining half being empty, the target is not in the array.

## ***Interpolation search***

Instead of calculating the midpoint, interpolation search estimates the position of the target value, taking into account the lowest and highest elements in the array as well as length of the array. This is only possible if the array elements are numbers. It works on the basis that the midpoint is not the best guess in many cases. For example, if the target value is close to the highest element in the array, it is likely to be located near the end of the array.
To find the position to be searched, it uses following formula.

> pos = lo + [ (x-arr[lo])*(hi-lo) / (arr[hi]-arr[Lo]) ]
>
> arr[] -> Array where elements need to be searched
>   x     -> Element to be searched
>   lo    -> Starting index in arr[]
>   hi    -> Ending index in arr[]

Source [Wikipedia Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

How you wish to implement them is at your own discretion.
If you are stuck with that and post the code of your attempt, we can help you more.

Comment: Thank You George !